# Is the Emperor really related to these people?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

I have just started reading Master of Mankind and within the first few pages you find out.

> The first human murdered (Abel) creates a Demon who I imagine will be part of the rest of the story

A bit further on you then see a child in the earliest days of the development of civilization avenge his father's death. It is then shown that this is one of the Emperors earliest memories.

So from this are we meant to read that the Emperor is the son of

> Abel

and the Nephew of

> Cain?

Comment: IIRC the Custodian he was sharing those visions with (Valdor?) was willing to admit to himself that the memories could have been fabricated for allegorical purposes.

Comment: Is the first human murdered called Abel in the book? I just finished to read the book and I missed that point...

Comment: @Vanguard3000: it is Ra Endymion, a tribune of the Custodes. But you are right: the Emperor confesses at the end that he is not sure the story happened that way (if it happened at all) but he wanted to teach something to Ra before he can fight the demon born from the first murder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**If you mean the vision he shared with Ra Endymion in chapter two, then I doubt so.**

Within the same vision The Emporer says.

> Men had killed each other for geneterations before my birth, but this was the first murder that had resonance to me, that changed my existence. it was illuminating.

He says that before him killing his father's murderer there have been many murders in previous genererations and even reffers to the first murder by saying that it was a simmilar type of murder (A fraticide).

So I think this means nothing more than just telling Ra where his idiology of ruling mankind comes from. And why it is important for **Him** to survive and lead the human race.

Comment: Was going to close this question as when I went back to my book I realised he himself states that the first Murder pre-dated him killing his uncle. In future, read a whole book before asking questions on stack :)

Answer (score 4):

### Probably not.

There are hundreds, maybe thousands versions of the origin of the Emperor: Whenever Adeptus Ministorum encounters a religion, it finds a way to put the Emperor somewhere there - if not as a main god in the pantheon, then as a deified hero (think Heracles or Gilgamesh). So most probably, the Eccelsiarchy put him into the important story from Abrahamic religions as a one of the first man.

The true origin is different: Thousands of neolithic shamans sacrificed themselves at the same time to create being with soul made of all those dead psykers, someone able to protect humanity from the encroaching Warp.

So what you are reading is either a Ecclesiarchy's half-forgotten propaganda... or a flat-out heresy.

Out of story answer:
While it is possible that the Black Library would try to retcon the origin, I doubt that this would happen any time soon. The official answer about information in BL books is that "everything is canon but not everything is true".

Comment: That's really cool, I hadn't heard of the shamanic self sacrifice thing before; where is that described?

Comment: @Paul if you are asking about a novel - then no, it hasn't been described there. Lots of love about WH40k comes from army codexes, RPG books etc. If you are interested in that, I highly recommend wiki pages: http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Emperor_of_Mankind http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Emperor_of_Mankind or (if you don't mind often informal language) the 1d4chan sites: https://1d4chan.org/wiki/God-Emperor_of_Mankind

Comment: So, nothing from GW, then?

Comment: Everything is from Games Workshop, but not in a novel form (so not in the Black Library)  - The RPG books (Rogue Trader, Dark Heresy etc) and WH40k Army Codex are DEFINITELY Games Workshop products :)

Comment: All the links you cited are wiki's, so I wasn't clear.

Comment: To be clear, I'm fine with all the GW supplements, it's just wiki's can be sketchy. Even the first one says about the origins of the emperor that "canonicity may be questionable"

Comment: Yes, but wiki takes the info from the Games Workshop books - i.e. the sacrifice of Shamans and birth of Emperor is described in the Rogue Trader RPG, a Games Workshop book. All the wiki information is taken from official sources, 1d4Chan tends to digress and adds theories, but it marks when the story is hypothetical (or when it is no longer canon).

Comment: Yes, GW is well known of retcons - the oldest version describes the sacrifice of shamans. There are others - i.e. that Emperor is some sort of a machine from Dark Age of Technology. In this world there is no absolute, universal truth.

Comment: What you're saying is dead-on, but only in terms of M41, when the Ecclesiarchy reigned supreme. It didn't exist during the Horus Heresy - though propagandists and the fervent Word Bearers did similar stuff. OP was specifically asking about supposed biographical information coming straight from the horse's mouth - The Emperor Himself.

Comment: Am pretty sure the Shamonic sacrifice idea has been unofficially retconnected by Black Library now, especially with the creation of perpetuals and the fact that big E has been indicated to be a perpetual himself. Also the vision given to RA in the master of Mankind is from his time as a child, now while this vision could be for other reasons the fact that he never mentions about being created by Shamans suggests that GW have decided to quietly back away from that whole idea.